# Quasi-particle distribution in Fermi liquid theory

Tags: many-body, quasiparticles, fermi-liquids

In Fermi liquid theory, the quasi-particle is well-defined only near the Fermi surface. However, in calculating specific heat and compressibility, we also assume that the quasi-particle obeys the Fermi-Dirac distribution
$$
n_{k\sigma} = 1/(e^{\beta \epsilon_k}+1),
$$
where $\epsilon_k$ is the renormalized energy of excitations. For example, the entropy is given by
$$
S = -k_B\sum_{k\sigma}\left[n_{k\sigma}\ln n_{k\sigma}+(1-n_{k\sigma})\ln(1-n_{k\sigma})\right].
$$

Since quasi-particles only exist near the Fermi surface, how do we interpret the quasi-particle distribution away from the Fermi surface?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quasiparticle distribution indeed does not have any physical meaning unless you are close to the Fermi surface. However, observe that if the temperature $T$ is small enough (as it must be for Fermi liquid theory to be valid), then far away from the Fermi surface, where $|\epsilon_k - \mu| \gg T$, the occupation number $n_k$ according to the Fermi-Dirac distribution is just frozen to be zero or one, and does not change when you vary $T$ or the chemical potential $\mu$. Thus, it's only the states close to the Fermi surface, where the quasiparticles are well-defined, that actually contribute to the specific heat or the compressibility.